# Extreme 670-48x.10 web interface

Tags: switch

How is the http interface enabled on this switch? What are the cli commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://documentation.extremenetworks.com/exos/downloads/EXOS_User_Guide_21_1.pdf

Page 706. You should at least make an effort to research before posting something like that here.

Comment: I understand your critique and appreciate the response.. I was in a bind and seeking a quick answer.